# Find large strings allocation during java debug session

Tags: java, string

After analyzing a heap dump I found that there were some 30MB strings allocated (single string of 30 MB).
Is there a way to set a break point while debugging the application so I can find the code which allocates these huge strings?
Since thousands of strings are allocated during application run it isn't possible just putting a break point on each string allocation.
I believe conditional break point will be too slow as well.
If possible I would want to exam those strings content to understand the origin of these allocation.
For example they may be a result of a web service call which usually is called with small amount of data but in rare cases with huge input (which are the cases I want to find).

Comment: this might get close to it: keep monitoring heap for String objects, once you see spike, take a thread dump immediately

Comment: I guess in theory a JVM could be run in a debug mode that recorded the location of the `new` that created each object... but whether there is such a JVM, I don't know.

Comment: @Raedwald strings are immutable; it's enough to have something like `if(length() > 300000) /* breakpoint */;` in the constructor

Comment: Once I had a problem with large memory consumption when I've used `"huge string".substring(few chars)` saved in a collection could take a huge amount of space in Java6 and earlier.

Comment: I like the approach of a conditional breakpoint in the string constructor(s) too but the OP suggested that this is not viable because of the overhead of the breakpoint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd try the conditional breakpoint, even if it meant leaving the app running for a day or two. At least then you can get on with something else while it is running. And any other solution is likely to take a day or two to implement anyway.

Failing that, you could using AspectJ to add pointcut into the String constructors and use that to log a message, throw an exception etc. This is basically the same as a conditional breakpoint but should run more quickly.

Answer (score 3):

Although you explicitly asked for a *debug session*, I assume that this was mainly an attempt to solve the actual problem: Large strings are allocated, and you don't know where this happens.

The allocations can be traced with [jVisualVM](http://visualvm.java.net/). You can start jVisualVM and your program, and connect the jVisualVM to your program.

If this does not suit your needs, I can delete this answer. Otherwise, here's how you can do it:

In the "Profiler" tab you can check the "Settings" checkbox in the upper right, and select the "Memory Settings" tab. There you can set the "Record allocation stack traces" checkbox:

[image: StringAlloc01]

Then, after pressing the "Memory" button at the top, the profiler will collect the information about the string allocations. After the application has exited (or after a snapshot has been taken), you can examine the recorded stack traces to find the method that allocates the large string - in this example, `method4`:

[image: StringAlloc02]

Comment: Will this show me the total memory for the stack trace or specific instances of the huge strings allocated? (I'm looking for a single string instance which was allocated with 30MB of data)

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you mean by a "specific instance". You will *not* see the *contents* of the string. But (as shown in the second screenshot), you'll receive a browsable view of the allocation stack traces. These are by default sorted by the number of bytes. So you can probably find the site of the "large" allocation by unfolding the first 3 levels of the largest `char[]` chunk. (Again: This is just one approach that is likely to lead to the required insights, but I can't guarantee that it will work for your application case)

Answer (score 2):

1. Copy the source code of `java.lang.String` from JDK sources to your
   project
2. Create a method in your **String.java** like below (count is an existing instance variable of `java.lang.String`)

   `private void checkSize(){ 
       if(count>1000000) //1MB 
         System.out.println(count); 
    }`
3. Edit `java.lang.String` to call this method `checkSize()` at the end of every **constructor**
4. **Add breakpoint** at the line System.out.println(count);
5. Add the new `java.lang.String` to **bootstrap** classpath
6. This breakpoint will break only when a String of size > 1MB  gets created